# Automatically create n calls of a function within a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, python-class, adafruit-circuitpython

I have been working on a project using circuitpython and neopixels as a way to learn how to use on-board timers. I'm 90% of the way through my functionality todo list and am now worried that I may need to rebuild the entire thing to get the last 10%.

The project is designed to blink n neopixels in firefly patterns.  There is a function for each type of firefly  pattern.  At the start of the script I create as many variables as there are lights.  I then loop through them, turning the light on or off depending on the timer.

I managed to do all of this manually (create 'variable_1, variable_2, ...' based on how many lights there are) and am now trying to automatically spawn the number of variables based on the number of lights. I also want to randomly assign the blink pattern to the light each time the script starts, but I think that's the last piece.

As you can see from the code below, I have managed to automatically create the variables based on the number of lights at the top.  However, things fall apart when I try and do something similar in the while loop at the bottom. Is my problem basically "this is why classes exist, so rewrite this entire thing to use classes"?  Or is there some other way to make this work?

thanks!

```
#https://www.nps.gov/grsm/learn/nature/firefly-flash-patterns.htm

import board
import digitalio
import time
import neopixel
import random



#variables to hold the color that the LED will blink
neo_r = 255
neo_g = 255
neo_b = 0

# variable to hold the number of neopixels
number_of_lights = 7

#create the neopixel. auto_write=True avoids having to push changes (at the cost of speed, which probably doesn't matter here)
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.NEOPIXEL, number_of_lights, brightness = 0.2, auto_write=False)

# automatically spins up the seed reset times for each light
reset_time_dict = {}

# sets the seeds to zero
for i in range(0, number_of_lights):
    var_name = 'resetTime' + str(i)
    reset_time_dict[var_name] = time.monotonic()


print(reset_time_dict)

def on(light_num):
    pixels[light_num] = (neo_r, neo_g, neo_b)
    pixels.show()
def off(light_num):
    pixels[light_num] = (0, 0, 0)
    pixels.show()

def brimleyi(reset_time_input, light_number):
    #calculates how much time has passed since the new zero
    time_from_zero = time.monotonic() - reset_time_input
    # creates the carry over reset_time variable so that it can be returned even if it is not updated in the last if statement
    reset_time = reset_time_input

    # on flash
    if 5 <= time_from_zero <= 5.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 15 <= time_from_zero <= 15.5:
        on(light_number)

    # reset (includes 10 seconds after second flash - 5 on the back end and 5 on the front end)
    elif time_from_zero > 20:
        off(light_number)
        reset_time = time.monotonic() + random.uniform(-3, 3)

    # all of the off times
    else:
        off(light_number)

    return reset_time

def macdermotti (reset_time_input, light_number):
    #calculates how much time has passed since the new zero
    time_from_zero = time.monotonic() - reset_time_input
    # creates the carry over reset_time variable so that it can be returned even if it is not updated in the last if statement
    reset_time = reset_time_input

    # on flash
    if 3 <= time_from_zero <= 3.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 5 <= time_from_zero <= 5.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 10 <= time_from_zero <= 10.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 12 <= time_from_zero <= 12.5:
        on(light_number)

    elif time_from_zero > 14.5:
        off(light_number)
        reset_time = time.monotonic() + random.uniform(-3, 3)

    else:
        off(light_number)

    return reset_time

def carolinus(reset_time_input, light_number):
    time_from_zero = time.monotonic() - reset_time_input
    # creates the carry over reset_time variable so that it can be returned even if it is not updated in the last if statement
    reset_time = reset_time_input

    if 0 <= time_from_zero <= 0.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 1 <= time_from_zero <= 1.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 2 <= time_from_zero <= 2.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 3 <= time_from_zero <= 3.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 4 <= time_from_zero <= 4.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 5 <= time_from_zero <= 5.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 6 <= time_from_zero <= 6.5:
        on(light_number)

    elif time_from_zero >= 15:
        off(light_number)
        reset_time = time.monotonic()

    else:
        off(light_number)

    return reset_time



while True:

    reset_time_dict["resetTime2"] = brimleyi(reset_time_dict["resetTime2"], 2)
    reset_time_dict["resetTime3"] = brimleyi(reset_time_dict["resetTime3"], 3)
    reset_time_dict["resetTime4"] = macdermotti(reset_time_dict["resetTime4"], 4)
    reset_time_dict["resetTime5"] = carolinus(reset_time_dict["resetTime5"], 5)
    reset_time_dict["resetTime6"] = carolinus(reset_time_dict["resetTime6"], 6)





    #briefly pauses the loop to avoid crashing the USB bus. Also makes it easier to see what is happening.
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this but the simplest change to support a variable number of NeoPixels is to loop over them with a `for` loop. Python allows functions to be treated as variables which is useful here. Maintaining the existing firefly pattern and repeating it can be achieved with a `tuple` and then calling the appropriate function in the loop. Something like this should work:

```
firefly_pattern = (brimleyi, brimleyi, macdermotti, carolinus, carolinus)
start_pixel = 2

while True:

    for pixel_pos in range(start_pixel, number_of_lights):
        key = "resetTime" + str(pixel_pos)
        firefly_fn = firefly_pattern[(pixel_pos - start_pixel) % len(firefly_pattern)]
        reset_time_dict[key] = firefly_fn(reset_time_dict[key], pixel_pos)

    #briefly pauses the loop to avoid crashing the USB bus. Also makes it easier to see what is happening.
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

You could change the three firefly functions to be a general class which manages the on/off transitions. There's a "class-less" very simple version of this in [Adafruit Learn: Multi-tasking with CircuitPython: Multiple LEDs](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-with-circuitpython/multiple-leds). I think I'd only invest time in that if there are more types to be added or you want to do gradual pulsations rather than abrupt flashes or add synchronous group behaviour.

It would be more efficient to put a single call to the `pixels.show()` at the end of the `while` loop and not do it inside `on`/`off`. There's also a performance gain from having `brightness=1` and just using 51 instead of 255 to achieve the same thing. These optimisations will become important if you start using a large number (100?) of NeoPixels.

If your code is going to run for more than a day or on a board that's been powered up for days then it's worth using `time.monotonic_ns` if your board supports it.

BTW, what's the story behind the comment about USB on the penultimate line?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this!  To answer your last question, without it the script was looping so quickly that the fan on my laptop kicked into high gear without any real benefit.  It also was looping so quickly that it was impossible to actually see any of my troubleshooting print statements.

Answer (score 0):

The KevinJWalters answer above has some helpful tips and options. I did end up rebuilding the script with classes for each individual light. The updated script is here in case it is helpful to anyone:

```
#https://www.nps.gov/grsm/learn/nature/firefly-flash-patterns.htm

import board
import digitalio
import time
import neopixel
import random



#variables to hold the color that the LED will blink
neo_r = 255
neo_g = 255
neo_b = 0

# variable to hold the number of neopixels
number_of_lights = 10

#create the neopixel. auto_write=True avoids having to push changes (at the cost of speed, which probably doesn't matter here)
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.NEOPIXEL, number_of_lights, brightness = 0.1, auto_write=False)

# sets up the bug holder list, which holds all of the bug objects 

bug_holder = []

    
# sets up the bug class

class Bug:
    def __init__(self, type, reset_time_input, light_number):
        self.type = type 
        self.reset_time_input = reset_time_input
        self.light_number = light_number 
        
    
#functions to turn light on and off 
def on(light_num):
    pixels[light_num] = (neo_r, neo_g, neo_b)
    pixels.show()
def off(light_num):
    pixels[light_num] = (0, 0, 0)
    pixels.show()
    

#functions for the types of fireflies 
def brimleyi(reset_time_input, light_number):
    #calculates how much time has passed since the new zero
    time_from_zero = time.monotonic() - reset_time_input
    # creates the carry over reset_time variable so that it can be returned even if it is not updated in the last if statement
    reset_time = reset_time_input

    # on flash
    if 5 <= time_from_zero <= 5.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 15 <= time_from_zero <= 15.5:
        on(light_number)

    # reset (includes 10 seconds after second flash - 5 on the back end and 5 on the front end)
    elif time_from_zero > 20:
        off(light_number)
        reset_time = time.monotonic() + random.uniform(-3, 3)

    # all of the off times
    else:
        off(light_number)

    return reset_time

def macdermotti (reset_time_input, light_number):
    #calculates how much time has passed since the new zero
    time_from_zero = time.monotonic() - reset_time_input
    # creates the carry over reset_time variable so that it can be returned even if it is not updated in the last if statement
    reset_time = reset_time_input

    # on flash
    if 3 <= time_from_zero <= 3.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 5 <= time_from_zero <= 5.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 10 <= time_from_zero <= 10.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 12 <= time_from_zero <= 12.5:
        on(light_number)

    elif time_from_zero > 14.5:
        off(light_number)
        reset_time = time.monotonic() + random.uniform(-3, 3)

    else:
        off(light_number)

    return reset_time

def carolinus(reset_time_input, light_number):
    time_from_zero = time.monotonic() - reset_time_input
    # creates the carry over reset_time variable so that it can be returned even if it is not updated in the last if statement
    reset_time = reset_time_input

    if 0 <= time_from_zero <= 0.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 1 <= time_from_zero <= 1.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 2 <= time_from_zero <= 2.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 3 <= time_from_zero <= 3.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 4 <= time_from_zero <= 4.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 5 <= time_from_zero <= 5.5:
        on(light_number)
    elif 6 <= time_from_zero <= 6.5:
        on(light_number)

    elif time_from_zero >= 15:
        off(light_number)
        reset_time = time.monotonic()

    else:
        off(light_number)

    return reset_time


#create all of the light objects by appending a new light object to the list for each neopixel
#the first argument (random.randint(1, 3)) is used to assign a random number which corresponds to one of the ff functions
#if you start adding lots of those it might be worth using a universal variable

for i in range (0, number_of_lights):
    bug_holder.append(Bug(random.randint(1, 3), time.monotonic(), i))


while True:

    #iterates through all of the light objects in the bug_holder list 
    #use the series of if statements to match the randomly assigned number to the types of fireflies 
   
    for i in range (0, number_of_lights):
        if bug_holder[i].type == 1:
            bug_holder[i].reset_time_input = brimleyi(bug_holder[i].reset_time_input, i)
        elif bug_holder[i].type == 2:
            bug_holder[i].reset_time_input = macdermotti(bug_holder[i].reset_time_input, i)
        elif bug_holder[i].type == 3:
            bug_holder[i].reset_time_input = carolinus(bug_holder[i].reset_time_input, i)
        #this is just a catchall if there is some sort of error
        else:
            bug_holder[i].reset_time_input = brimleyi(bug_holder[i].reset_time_input, i)
            print("number error")
    
    
    #briefly pauses the loop to avoid crashing the USB bus. Also makes it easier to see what is happening.
    time.sleep(0.25)
```